# In invite an ear on sharing url to social media channels, app moves away from recent opened/ running apps list

Tags: android, android-toast, invite

Please find code below:

```
if (pos == 4) {
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();

sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Check out the App at: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + R.string.app_name);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
getActivity().startActivity(sendIntent);

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "INVITE & EARN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: What is your issue exactly?

Comment: We have used above code in our code for developing an app for invite/ sharing url to others to download app.  However on sharing the link our app disappears from the list of currently running apps.

Comment: While you share the app url suppose on gmail then it will create mail with your url and after sending it your app will remain open.